# Palavra reservada "this"

Tags: java

Eu gostaria de uma explicação com um exemplo se possível, sobre a palavra reservada `this` em Java, acabei não entendendo muito bem.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`this` se refere ao objeto atual. Leia sempre assim que ficará mais claro para você: `this object`

Exemplo:

```
public class Esse {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Esse esse1 = new Esse();
        Esse esse2 = new Esse();
        esse1.compara(esse2);
    }
    public void compara(Object aquele) {
        if(this == aquele) {
            System.out.println("mesmo objeto");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Objetos diferentes");
        }
    }
}
```

Resultado:

> Objetos diferentes

Dentro do main(), ao chamar o método compara() é passado implicitamente o objeto que o chamou, nesse caso o objeto `esse1`, logo a comparação dentro do método retornou falso, pois `esse1 != esse2`

Inclusive, costuma-se dizer que essa é a grande diferença de métodos e funções, pois quando é chamado um método seu objeto é passado implicitamente com ele, e o mesmo não ocorre com funções em outras linguagens, por exemplo Pascal.

Eu disse "costuma-se dizer" pois é o que algumas pessoas defendem (inclusive eu), mas apesar de tudo em Java ser método e nunca funções, existem os métodos estáticos que não possuem um objeto atrelados a ele, pois métodos estáticos pertencem a classe e não ao objeto, logo, não é necessário que exista um objeto criado para que eles sejam acessados.

Exemplo:

```
public static void teste() {
    System.out.println(this); //ERRADO!!
}
```

O código acima é inválido pois o método não pertence ao objeto, e sim à classe, logo o objeto `this` não é passado para o método que foi chamado.

O `this` também é muito comumente usado para explicitar de qual variável estamos falando, se é a variável do objeto ou se é uma variável local. Exemplo:

```
public class Exemplo {
    private int id;
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }   
}
```

Repare na linha `this.id = id`, ele está atribuindo o valor da variável local ao valor da variável do objeto que foi chamado o método set. Se não fosse possível recorrer ao `this` as variáveis deveriam possuir nomes distintos para o código funcionar corretamente.

Comment: Obrigado Math! Agora entendo! Só que apareceu mais uma dúvida similar. Já vi em códigos em que usam a palavra `this` em uma variável, por exemplo

> int numero;    
  void metodo(int numero) {    
      this.numero = numero;    
  }    
Este this.numero se refere a variável do objeto e não do método?

Comment: @BrunoNeuman exato! Obrigado por lembrar, vou incrementar e resposta.

Comment: Obrigado novamente :)

Comment: Eu uso o `this` para enviar o próprio objeto para um método, ex.: `ClasseChecagens.checaDados(this)`.

Comment: @Patrick sim, é mais uma aplicação para a palavra reservada. Talvez um pouco menos comum, diria eu, mas igualmente correta.