# Como "chamar" o this corretamente?

Tags: java, android

Quando os Elementos estão dentro do `onCreate`, usar o **(this)** é muito fácil...

**Exemplo 1 : que funciona de dentro do próprio onCreate**

```java
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.memo_confirmation_spinner);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
}
```

**Exemplo 2: Outra classe**

Já se eu a coloco dentro uma função (fora do `onCreate`), a coisa muda e a seguinte função não funciona. O compilador não aceita esse `this` pois ele não acha o `onCreate`:

```java
public class JSONOAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {
            Log.e("****** MESSAGE ******", " Json Object  = " + JSONParser.getJSONFromUrl( URL ).get("ReportDetailTextList"));

            Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.memo_confirmation_spinner);
            spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);  // NESTE EXEMPLO, ESTA DANDO ERRO NESTE THIS
        }
        catch (Exception e) {}
    }
}
```

Ou seja, no Exemplo 2 o Android Studio já nao aceita mais o `this`.

Qual é a maneira **correta de escrever este último `this`*(para o Exemplo 2)*?

Comment: `this` faz referência a instância da própria classe. Quando você diz que não funciona, o que quer dizer exatamente? Pode melhorar a questão para deixar isso mais claro?

Comment: Talvez ajude [Palavra reservada “this”](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/27197/91). Aparece algum erro/exception? ou é um resultado inesperado? o Android Studio fornece algum hint (na linha como problema)?

Comment: não ficou claro qual é a sua dúvida... qual é o erro?

Comment: Editei a pergunta, espero ter ficado claro...   chamar o THIS fora do on create, nao esta funcionando........

Comment: @ldeoliveira, respondendo sua pergunta, quando uso  o segundo exemplo, ou seja uma funcao fora do "onCreate", o androide nao deixa continuar.. simples assim! ele sublinha toda aquela linha de vermelho!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

O primeiro fator que deve-se observar nesta situação é que chamar o método `setOnItemSelectedListener()` impõe a implementação da interface`AdapterView.onItemSelectedListener` na classe. Um exemplo:

```
public class JSONOAsyncTask 
    extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> 
    implements  AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{
    ...

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
}
```

Outro fator é que deve-se explorar mais o [**`AsyncTask`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). Esta classe nos fornece algumas *features* interessantes: `onPreExecute()` e `onPostExecute()`. Estes métodos servem para definirmos alguma ação que desejamos executar antes da tarefa assíncrona e o que desejamos fazer depois que a tarefa for concluída.

#### Vamos ao `this`

Primeiro você deve saber, como toda linguagem de programação, que existem algumas palavras reservadas. No JAVA, possui o *this* e o *super*, respectivamente as instruções `this()` e `super()`.

As palavras chave se dividem em categorias conforme o seu propósito. Algumas palavras são usadas em mais de um cenário. O significado da palavra depende do contexto onde é usado. Isso se chamada: carga semântica. Java, por ter poucas palavras chave e propositalmente reaproveitar as palavras sempre que possível tem um carga semântica bastante maior que outras linguagens. Contudo, na prática não é possível confundir os vários significados.

A palavra reservada ***super*** é utilizada para fazer referencia a métodos ou atributos da super classe. Imagina que você tenha uma classe chamada de Gerente que herda da classe Funcionário e que ambas as classes possuem um método chamado `calcularPontos()`. Estando na classe Gerente como fazer para chamar o método `calcularPontos()` da superclasse (Funcionario)?

```
//o compilador sabe que você quer utilizar o método da superclasse e não o método local.
super.calcularPontos();
```

Já palavra reservada ***this*** é utilizada normalmente dentro de métodos que recebem parâmetros com o mesmo nome de atributos de instância da classe ou para fazer **referência ao próprio objeto**, vamos à um exemplo:

```
public void setNome(String nome){
    /*o this nesse caso informar que o atributo de instancia 
    "nome" vai receber o valor do paramentro "nome". 
     Se não tivesse o this, como ele saberia? ficaria ambiguo.*/
    this.nome = nome; 
}
```

Outro exemplo, imagine que você esteja na classe `Gerente` e chama o método de outra classe que espera como argumento um objeto da classe `Gerente`. Daí você pode utilizar o `this` para fazer isso.

```
/* o método salvar gerente espera como argumento um objeto da classe
Gerente, como estou dentro da classe gerente eu disse que o 
objeto a ser salvo é "este"(this).*/
Armazenamento.salvarGerente(this);
```

> this: usado para indicar que o escopo pretendido para a invocação de
>   um método ou acesso a um atributo é o do **próprio objeto** corrente.
>   Também utilizado para fazer referencia a um outro construtor da mesma
>   classe. É usando ainda como forma de referir a instância que encapsula
>   a instância corrente quando em uma classe aninhada

Uma comparação

> super: usado para indicar que o escopo pretendido para a invocação de
>   um método ou acesso a um atributo é o da classe mãe.Também utilizado
>   para fazer referencia a um outro construtor da classe imediatamente
>   superior na hierarquia de herança

### Situação

Veja uma forma como você poderia resolver este caso. Primeiro implementando o `AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener` à superclasse `JSONAsyncTask`. Logo depois declarando o `Spinner` como variável global. No `onPreExecute` é feita a ligação entre o XML e JAVA, que seria antes de executar o `doInBackGround`. Em *background* é criado a lista de categorias, como exemplo, e também a definição do adaptador. Por fim, no `onPostExecute`, é anexado os dados ao adaptador. Abaixo segue exatamente como deveria está seu `AsyncTask` personalizado:

```
public class JSONOAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> implements  AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{

    private Spinner spinner;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {

        // criando lista de elementos
        List<String> categories = new ArrayList<String>();
        categories.add("Balaco Bacco");
        categories.add("Capitão G. Nascimento");
        categories.add("JBuenos's Dias");
        categories.add("Marceleza");
        categories.add("Ramarelo");

        // criação do adapter
        dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, categories);

        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        return false;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {

        // anexando o adapter aos dados
        spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
}
```

Recentemente eu fiz uma pergunta que é [Qual diferença entre os métodos para obter um contexto?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/180349/qual-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-os-m%C3%A9todos-para-obter-um-contexto/), onde comento que podemos além do `this`, obter o contexto de várias formas, com diferentes métodos, como `getApplicationContext()` e o `getBaseContext()` que aparentemente tem o mesmo propósito. Dê uma lida nas respostas e veja mais detalhes sobre o modo de usar.

Referência

- [Palavras Reservadas](http://www.javabuilding.com/academy/java-language/palavras-reservadas.html)

Comment: OBRIGADA!  ja estou estudando!!! como sempre uma resposta completa!

Comment: @ramaral encontrei uma situação no qual realmente precisei usar o `getBaseContext()`. Neste caso, precisamente não seria tão ideal usar o `getApplicationContext()`.

Comment: consegui implementar!!  OBRIGADA MAIS UMA VEZ! agora vou estudar tudo isso.... que dor...  so sofri assim antes por conta de aprender C.. que na verdade, sei bem pouco ainda...  affe.. como tem coisa.. conceito...linguagem pra entender...   bom, la vou eu

Comment: OLHA que interessnte... 500 pontos redondinhos....  quem sabe signifique algo... rsrs

Comment: @CamilaYamamoto legal que deu tudo certo por ai. Pois bem, crescer dói. Você está crescendo, aprendendo, é cansativo, mas vale a pena. Conhecimento nunca é demais.

Comment: rsrs.. sim.. tenho percebido isso de crescer...  rsrsr !    BOM, nao deu tudo certo, apareceram outros erros...  rsrs...  MAS percebo que essa parte do (this) funcionou, e assim vou poder estudar, ja os "proximos erros" to tentando entender aqui!  :D

Comment: desolada aqui... Passei o dia pesquisando isso e nada.... APARECEU mais um erro que simplesmente nao sei do que se trata..  o máximo que posso dizer eh que,  (talvez) o spinner nao tenha achado a ARRAY..    **Depois que o APP trava, o erro aparece na linha** _spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);_, **sendo que no console  o código que aparece eh:** _...Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.app.Activity.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference..._

Comment: @AckLay Não vejo porque precise de usar aí `getBaseContext()` pode usar o context da Activity o `this`.

Comment: @ramaral não, não é possível usar o `this` no método `doInBackground` a não ser que eu insira o `MinhaActivityPrincipal.this` em vez de somente `this`. Então não sei, ainda estou procurando seu legado.

Comment: @CamilaYamamoto quanto a esse erro que está acontecendo, você tem que ver qual `id` está definido para seu `spinner`. Aparentemente talvez não esteja definindo corretamente, ou esteja usando o `spinner` antes mesmo de instanciar.

Comment: @AckLay Sim, dentro de uma *inner class*, para referenciar a *outer class*, tem de usar `NomeDaOuterClasse.this`.

Comment: legal!!! estudando!! Bom eu conferi do ID direitinho, ta idêntico!  mas eu nao consegui resolver, então fiz mais uma pergunta no SO,  assim nao fica coisa demais em um só post! (http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/180980/o-que-eh-como-resolver-um-erro-null-object-reference-que-aparece-no-cons)

Answer (score 6):

> Qual é a maneira correta de escrever este ultimo THIS? (para o exemplo 2)??

### Resposta curta:

Se a classe JSONOAsyncTask está declarada dentro(inner class) da Activity(outer class) e esta implementar a interface AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener, em vez de `this` deve usar `NomeDaActivity.this`.

### Explicação:

`this` é uma palavra reservada que, neste contexto, é uma referência ao objecto actual. É como se fosse uma variável que guarda o objecto actual.
Neste caso o objecto actual é a *inner class* assim para referenciar a Activity(*outer class*) deverá incluir o seu nome: `NomeDaOuterClasse.this`

O método `setOnItemSelectedListener()` recebe, como argumento, um objecto que implemente a interface AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener.

Assim, se a Activity implementar a interface AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener, `this` pode ser usado, como argumento a `setOnItemSelectedListener()`, se a chamada for feita dentro dela, por exemplo, dentro do método `onCreate()`.

O mesmo se aplica ao segundo exemplo. Neste caso a classe é JSONOAsyncTask,  `this` agora refere-se a um objecto desse tipo.
Para poder ser usada como argumento de `setOnItemSelectedListener()`, a classe JSONOAsyncTask tem de implementar a interface AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener.

No entanto, se a classe JSONOAsyncTask está declarada dentro(inner class) da Activity(outer class) e esta implementar a interface AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener, use `NomeDaActivity.this` para a referenciar.

Answer (score 2):

Porque quando voce usa o THIS dentro de um onClickListener, por exemplo, você está usando o this referente ao objeto onClickListener .
Perceba por exemplo, quando voce dá new onClickListener e dentro desse objeto (chamada classe anônima) você dá um this com a intenção de ser o da activity, mas na verdade nesse caso vai ser do objeto onClickListener criado.

Edit: no seu caso é na asynctask, mas o funcionamento é o mesmo.
Como está dentro da asynctask, vai ter que passar no construtor dela um this, que vai ser a activity, e depois usar esse parametro no spinner. 
Ex:

```
// na activity
MyAsync ma = new MyAsync(this); // 
ma.execute();

// na async
private Context contexto; // usa essa veriável onde voce tinha colocado o this
public MyAsync (Context contexto){
this.contexto = contexto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Como o @Pagotti falou o `this` faz referencia a propria classe, o que provavelmente esta acontecendo é que a classe `JSONOAsyncTask` esta no mesmo arquivo da classe onde esta o seu `onCreate()` certo?

Já que o `this` faz referencia a propria classe (tipo localhost, que aponta sempre para a propria maquina) o `this` na verdade é do tipo `JSONOAsyncTask` que é uma extensao de `AsyncTask` que por sua vez é o tipo incorreto para o parametro `setOnItemSelectedListener()`

**Vamos lá**

De acordo com a [documentação do metodo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html?hl=pt-br#setOnItemSelectedListener(android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener)) 
`setOnItemSelectedListener(AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener listener)`

O parametro deve ser uma instancia da classe `AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener` como você usou o `this` a sua classe deve ter implementado os metodos `onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)` e `onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent)` provavelmente você fez isso e por isso o primeiro exemplo funciona.

Já no segundo exemplo sua classe não implementa a classe `AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener` já que não implementa a classe logo os metodos (citados acima) não existem, e é isso que deve estar levando ao seu erro.

Answer (score 0):

Passei pelas mesmas dificuldades A palavra reservada `this` é usada quando o método faz referencia ao próprio objeto. Por exemplo, `mainActivity`.

O AS não aceita quando a referencia é feita a outro objeto. Por exemplo, um `fragment` não vai aceitar referencias a `this`.

O que você vai usar no lugar dele, depende do caso de quem faz referencia a quem. Por exemplo, num fragmento, você pode usar `getActivity()` no lugar de `this`.

O próprio Android Studio dá dicas do que ele espera ver. Basta deixar o mouse sobre `this` sublinhado de vermelho.

Detalhe: `THIS` no Android, não existe, tem de ser sempre `this` em minusculas. Só comento porque alguém poderá ler isso no futuro e se confundir.

Comment: Aquela segunda frase não está "muito correcta" e até contradiz a primeira.

Comment: Estimado @ramaral, por gentileza, corrija-me. E me explique em que elas se contradizem, até para que eu possa me expressar melhor.

Comment: Na primeira você diz: "faz referencia ao próprio objeto" na segunda diz: "um fragment não vai aceitar referencias a this". A primeira está correcta, `this` refere-se ao objecto actual, a segunda contradiz porque dá a entender que um fragment não "aceita" `this`. `this`pode ser usado em qualquer objecto, ele fará sempre referência a esse objecto. A questão prende-se ao seu uso como argumento de um método, ele tem de ser do tipo que o método espera.

Comment: Realmente, foi uma escolha de palavras ruins. Obrigado por esclarecer

Answer (score 0):

como o @Pagotti comentou, o "this" faz referencia a uma classe e só está disponível dentro dessa mesma classe, assim no caso aqui, o melhor seria voce fazer assim ó:

```
spiner.OnItemClickListener listener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long id) {
        // ...
        int p = position;
        // ...
    }
};
```

tenta ai usando o seu próprio código dentro da chamada do método onItemClick.

epero que ajude!