# Qual diferença entre os métodos para obter um contexto?

Tags: android, android-context

Pode-se, além do `this`, obter o contexto de várias formas, com diferentes métodos. Como mostra no código abaixo, temos o `getApplicationContext()` e o `getBaseContext()` que aparentemente tem o mesmo propósito.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    public Context context;

    public void umMetodoQualquer() {
        context = this;
        context = getApplicationContext();
        context = getBaseContext();
    }
}
```

E na prática, quais são as diferenças entre os métodos para obter um contexto?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Eles retornam "tipos" diferentes de Context, com tempos de vida e acesso a *resources* diferentes.

[Context](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) é uma classe abstracta, implementada internamente pela classe [ContextImpl](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/app/ContextImpl.java#203).
Os vários "tipos"(comportamentos) de Context são obtidos recorrendo a *factory [methods](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/app/ContextImpl.java#ContextImpl.createActivityContext%28android.app.ActivityThread%2Candroid.app.LoadedApk%2Candroid.os.IBinder%29)* de ContextImpl.

Publicamente, um Context é disponibilizado através de classes herdadas de [ContextWrapper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html).
ContextWrapper herda de Context e implementa os seus métodos de forma a simplesmente delegarem as chamadas a outro Context(ContextImpl).
Isto permite que subclasses, como Application, Service e Activity(indirectamente através de [ContextThemeWrapper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ContextThemeWrapper.html)), modifiquem o seu comportamento sem alterar o Context original.

- `this` - Neste caso refere-se a uma Activity. O seu tempo de vida está ligado ao tempo de vida da Activity e, através dele, acede-se aos *resources*<sup>(1)</sup> definidos para esta Activity.

  ```
  java.lang.Object
     ↳    android.content.Context
         ↳    android.content.ContextWrapper
             ↳    android.view.ContextThemeWrapper
                 ↳    android.app.Activity
  ```
- `getApplicationContext()` - Refere-se à aplicação. O seu tempo de vida está ligado ao tempo de vida da aplicação e, através dele, acede-se aos *resources*<sup>(1)</sup> definidos para a aplicação.

  ```
  java.lang.Object
     ↳    android.content.Context
         ↳    android.content.ContextWrapper
             ↳    android.app.Application
  ```
- `getBaseContext()` - Retorna o *context* que foi utilizado ao criar o objecto ContextWrapper, passado ao construtor ou a ele atribuído pelo método `attachBaseContext()`. Ele é do tipo ContextImpl.

  ```
  java.lang.Object
     ↳    android.content.Context
         ↳    android.content.ContextImpl
  ```

  Se a subclasse de ContextWrapper não sobrescrever nenhum dos métodos, o Context retornado, terá um comportamento igual ao da subclasse.
  Por exemplo, o context passado ao método `onReceive()` do BroadcastReceiver é do tipo [ReceiverRestrictedContext](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/app/ContextImpl.java#161). Nele os métodos `registerReceiver()` e `bindService()` são sobrescritos para lançar ReceiverCallNotAllowedException, caso seja chamados.

<sub><sup>(1)</sup> Por exemplo, se para esta Activity definir um *theme* diferente do *theme* da aplicação, as *views* criadas com o *context* `this` têm uma aparência diferente daquelas criadas com o *context* retornado por `getApplicationContext()`.</sub>

Pode verificar qual o tipo de cada Context, obtido por cada um dos métodos, usando este código:

```
activity = this;
applicationContext = getApplicationContext();
baseContext = getBaseContext();

Log.d("Context", activity.getClass().getName());
Log.d("Context", applicationContext.getClass().getName());
Log.d("Context", baseContext.getClass().getName());
```

Comment: O getbaseContext também refere-se a Activity ou seria algo mais complexo?

Comment: getbaseContext() retorna o context criado pelo sistema, uma instância de ContextImp que é criada e configurada(suponho) em função do tipo de componente que o vai utilizar: Activity/Service  ou Application. Ele é acedido através do *proxy* ContextWrapper, do qual eles herdam. Cada um deles é um context mas a "implementação/configuração" dele é fornecida externamente.

Comment: Não sei se a classe Acrivity sobrescreve algum dos métodos de ContextWrapper. Se não sobrescreve o Context retornado por `getBaseContext()` terá um comportamento igual ao `(Context)this`.

Comment: Fiz os seguintes teste usando o logo: `this.getClass().getName()` retornou o nome da activity; `getApplicationContext().getClass().getName()` retornou `android.app.application`;  `getBaseContext().getClass().getName()` retornou `android.app.ContextImpl`.  Gostaria de saber na prática, como/quando/onde é usado. Teria como você exemplificar?

Comment: Use o Context  do componente dentro do qual você está(this), desde que a referência a ele não se estenda além do ciclo de vida desse componente. Se não for esse o caso use getApplicationContext(). Até agora não encontrei razão para usar getBaseContext(). Veja este [post](https://possiblemobile.com/2013/06/context/) onde tem informação mais completa.

Comment: Ainda estou com uma pulga atrás da orelha, mas vou validar a resposta, aí você coloca esse link do post (que é bem interessante) para uma questão de aprofundamento no assunto, que também é uma complementação. Obrigado.

Comment: Que dúvidas você ainda tem?

Comment: Por exemplo, esse `getBaseContext()` nem deveria existir, pois o `this` e o `getApplicationContext` já são suficiente considerando suas funcionalidades. Então por causa disso, também fiquei a pensar. No post que você passou não tem nenhuma referência sobre ele.

Comment: Normalmente um *wrapper/proxy* não expõe o(s) objecto(s) internos. É possível que haja alguma situação em que seja útil/necessário usar `getBaseContext()`, eu ainda não encontrei nenhuma.

Answer (score 9):

`getApplicationContext()` como diz o nome esta associado ao contexto da aplicação e será o mesmo enquanto durar a aplicação.

Já `getBasecontext()` esta associado a atividade e será destruida junto com a atividade.

Comment: então `getBaseContext` é o mesmo que `this`?

Comment: Sim. this é o contexto atual, contexto da atividade em tela, ou do fragmento atual, o que nos obriga a buscar o contexto da aplicação para acessar algum método especifico.

Answer (score 5):

`this`: É o contexto atual da sua activity, pertence a activiy, quando a activiy for destruída, o contexto também será.
Obs: Estende de `Activity`, que pode sua vez, tambem estende de uma classe `Context`.

`getApplicationContext()`: É o contexto da aplicação, de todo o ciclo de vida da aplicação, quando a aplicação for destruída, em seguida, o contexto da aplicação também será.

`getBaseContext()`: É um método de `ContextWrapper`, é a implementação mais simples de contexto que delega todas as chamadas para outro contexto. Pode ser subclassificada para modificar o comportamento e alterar o contexto original.

**Quando usar:**

**Use this**: Quando você precisar apresentar Dialogs, AlertDialogs, etc, mensagens para o usuário na Activity que ele se encontra.

**Use getApplicationContext**: Use quando quer um context que seja independente do ciclo de vida da Activity, ou seja, que exista durante todo ciclo da aplicação.

**Use getBaseContext**: Quando você deseja acessar Contexto de outro contexto dentro do aplicativo você pode acessar.
Exemplo: Widgets, Views, etc..