# "O que eh"/"como resolver" um erro "null object reference" ? Que aparece no console?

Tags: java, android

Quando tento usar o codigo abaixo, *(que alias consegui chegar com ajuda dos amigos do SO)*  aparece um erro na linha: 
*spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);* 
Com o seguinte codigo no console:

> java.lang.RuntimeException:
>  
>             Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{
>             jp.co.e_grid.rakuseki/jp.co.e_grid.rakuseki.PostConfirmationActivity
>  
>         }: 
>  
>  
>             java.lang.NullPointerException:
>  
>                 Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.app.Activity.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference

**Eis o meu codigo:**

```
public class JSONOAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> implements  AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{

    private Spinner spinner;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById( R.id.memo_confirmation_spinner );
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {

            try {
                Log.e("****** MESSAGE ******", " Json Object  = " + JSONParser.getJSONFromUrl( URL ).get("ReportDetailTextList"));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // TEST: Temporaly list
            List<String> categories = new ArrayList<String>();
            categories.add("aaa");
            categories.add("bbb");
            categories.add("ccc");
            categories.add("ddd");
            categories.add("eee");

            // Adapter Creation

            // ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getBaseContext(), R.array.confirmation_memo, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            // adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

            dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, categories);
            dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

            return false;
        }

    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        // putting adapter in to data
        spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
}
```

**Detalhe importante:**
Quando chamo o mesmo *"spinner"*  de dentro do *OnCreate()* com esse mesmo ID, tudo funciona bem,  veja o trecho de código:

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.memo_confirmation_spinner);
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.confirmation_memo, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
// Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
// Apply the adapter to the spinner
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
// ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
// See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
```

Tenho lido outros posts sobre *"null object reference"* no SO mas me parece que tem muitas variações do mesmo erro, então fica minha pergunta: **A que essa mensagem de erro se refere e, como resolve-la?**

Comment: Olha, algum objeto que você está chamando não está sendo inicializado, agora basta descobrir qual. O correto seria tu "Debugar" até encontrar o objeto que dispara a exceção.

Comment: quando você fala _debugar_, seria colocar pontos de "parada no código" e eu acompanhando passo-a-passo?

Comment: Hum... Não entendo muito de Java, mas quando tu chama o trecho "spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this)" talvez o objeto spinner esteja nulo, daí dá a entender que a chamada acima  "(Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById( R.id.memo_confirmation_spinner );" não encontrou o objeto pelo Id (se for isso que a função faz)

Comment: Isso, Camila. É um bom começo, pelo menos você pode ver o estado do seu objeto e quando ele vai disparar o erro.

Comment: sim!!  debuguei! (obrigado pela dica! ) :D O spinner realmente vem _"null"_, mas o mesmo codigo, dentro do _"onCreate"_ funciona sem problemas!   o que pode ser? sobre ele nao conseguir "abrir" o spinner? estar dentro de um _AsyncTask_?? (inclusive ja corrigi a pergunta!)

Comment: Acho pouco provável ser porque é uma chamada assíncrona. Tens que ver primeiro se o Id realmente é o mesmo, ele pode estar indo como 0 ou nulo dentro do preOnExecute, por isso não encontra um objeto.

Comment: entendi @WilsonSantos, mas acontece que no AndroidStudio, nao eh possivel colocar um id errado, ele ja acusa o erro na hora que digita, e eu tambem confirmei com calma se esta escrito certo, sem contar que re-escrevi o codigo dentro do onCreate()  pra testar, e nessa hora ele funciona!com o mesmo id , inclusive...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resumidamente a exceção [NullPointerException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html) é lançada sempre que tentar acessar um objeto de memória que não tenha sido instanciado, ou melhor inicializado, até o momento de sua chamada.

**Primeiro fator** a ser observado, é que você está declarando duas variáveis do tipo `Spinner`, globalmente na sua *inner class* e dentro `onPreExecute()`. Declare apenas uma vez para que não ocorra o erro. Veja como ficaria seu método `onPreExecute()`:

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.memo_confirmation_spinner );
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
}
```

**Segundo fator** é que como está dizendo que o erro está nessa linha abaixo:

```
spinner = (Spinner) findViewById( R.id.memo_confirmation_spinner );
```

Tente observar na sua *out class* se não está chamando sua `JSONOAsyncTask` antes do `setContentView()`. Caso seja isso, só inverter fazendo desta forma:

```
setContentView(R.layout.sua_activity);
new JSONOAsyncTask.execute();
```

Comment: Interessante! preciso estudar mais isso de como declarar as variáveis, Bom já testei mas infelizmente, aparece  o mesmo erro... idêntico... (pra garantir que nao apareceria mais erros, comentei a parte do spinner que fica dentro do _"onCreate"_)

Comment: voltei! e abri mais um post!  se tiver um tempinho adoraria saber da sua dica/ideia naquele problema, por la me deram ideias.. bem... diferentes! http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/181026/como-fazer-um-array-criado-dentro-de-um-asynctask-ser-global/181067#181067