# Como fazer um Array criado dentro de um AsyncTask ser global?

Tags: java, android

Na minha versao original eu populava meu spinner a partir de uma Array, colocado no strings.xml

E para para saber qual selecao o usuario fez usava o seguinte codigo

**código 1**

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long id) {
    // get selected option
    String[] names = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.confirmation_memo);
    selectedName = names[position];

}
```

Mas agora eu pego o array de uma URL e, para isso, tive que implementar o metodo AsyncTask para pegar os dados OnLine, do site da emrpesa.

com o seguinte codigo:

**código 2**

```
    public class JSONOAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> implements  AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{

        private Spinner spinner;
        private ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            spinner = (Spinner) findViewById( R.id.memo_confirmation_spinner );
            spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(PostConfirmationActivity.this);
        }

            @Override
            protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {
                try {
                    Log.e("****** MESSAGE ******", " Json Object  = " + JSONParser.getJSONFromUrl( URL ).get("ReportDetailTextList"));

                    List < String > categories = new ArrayList < String > ();
                    JSONArray array = (JSONArray) JSONParser.getJSONFromUrl(URL).get("ReportDetailTextList");
                    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                        categories.add(array.get(i).toString());

                        // puting the first option from the URL, to be the "default memo field".
                        if(i == 0) {
                            selectedName = array.get(i).toString();
                        }

                    }
                    dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter < String > (getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, categories);
                    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return false;
            }

        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            // putting adapter in to data
            spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
   }

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    }
```

**E tudo funciona bem**, a nao ser que eu nao consigo fazer com que o *"código 1"*, passe a usar o array da URL(que eh criada dentro do AsyncTask)... e assim fazer a escolha no spinner,

> Ou seja:

dentro do AsyncTask, crio o ARRAY na linha:

```
JSONArray array = (JSONArray) SONParser.getJSONFromUrl(URL).get("ReportDetailTextList");
```

e gostaria de usar esse array FORA do AsyncTask, no codigo

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long id) {
    // get selected option
    String[] names = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.confirmation_memo);
    selectedName = names[position];

}
```

OU sera que existe uma forma melhor se pegar qual a escolha do spinner? seguindo a ideia de usar o AsyncTask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma simples solução para pegar o valor clicado no seu `Spinner` é criar uma variável na sua *out class* `PostConfirmationActivity`. Por exemplo `String selectedName`, que aparentemente já está criado, que irá receber o valor que você clicará ou seleciona.

Dentro do seu JSONAsyncTask, vai declarar da seguinte forma:

```
    private Spinner spinner;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter;
    private List<String> categories;
```

No `doInBackground`:

```
 try {
     Log.e("****** MESSAGE ******", " Json Object  = " + JSONParser.getJSONFromUrl(URL).get("ReportDetailTextList"));

     categories = new ArrayList <String> ();
     JSONArray array = (JSONArray) JSONParser.getJSONFromUrl(URL).get("ReportDetailTextList");
     for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
         categories.add(array.get(i).toString());

         // puting the first option from the URL, to be the "default memo field".
         if (i == 0) {
             selectedName = array.get(i).toString();
         }    
     }
     dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter < String > (getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, categories);
     dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

 } catch (JSONException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

No se seu `onItemSelected`:

```
// esse spinnerClicado você tem que declarar na sua inner class PostConfirmationActivity
// dai então você poderá usar ela em qualquer local
selectedName = categories.get(position);

// esse toast é só para mostrar para o usuário qual item ele clicou
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),""+categories.get(position),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: simples! agora ela eh global...  vacilo meu.. VALEU! MUITO!

Answer (score 4):

Você pode adotar uma estratégia um pouco diferente, hoje, pelo que vi sua classe `JSONOAsyncTask` faz a requisição e interpreta a resposta dentro da própria classe.

Isso pode ser ruim na hora que você tiver que fazer requisição e tiver que interpretar a reposta de forma diferente, por isso, sugiro que você crie uma interface `Listener`, fazendo com que cada classe que invocar tua classe `AsyncTask`, analise e interprete a resposta de forma diferente.

**Exemplo de Listener**:

```
public interface AsyncTaskCompleteListener<JSONObject> {
    public void onTaskComplete(org.json.JSONObject result) throws JSONException;
}
```

**Classe do WebService**

```
public class WebServiceTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{

    public static final int POST_TASK = 1;
    public static final int GET_TASK = 2;
    public static final int DELETE_TASK = 3;
    public static final int PUT_TASK = 4;

    public JSONObject returnWS;

    private static final String TAG = "WebServiceTask";

    //Time out para conexão em milisegundos
    private static final int CONN_TIMEOUT = 7000;

    //Tempo de timeout em milisegundos para espera dos dados... (5 segundos é pouco e 10 é muito, escolhido 7 por ser a média)
    private static final int SOCKET_TIMEOUT = 7000;

    private int taskType = GET_TASK;
    private Context mContext = null;
    private String processMessage = "Processando...";
    private AsyncTaskCompleteListener<String> callback;
    private boolean hideProcessMessage = false;
    private String msgErro;

    private ArrayList<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

    private ProgressDialog pDlg = null;

    public WebServiceTask(int taskType, Context mContext, String processMessage, AsyncTaskCompleteListener<String> cba) {
        this.taskType = taskType;
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.processMessage = processMessage;
        this.callback = cba;
    }


    private void showProgressDialog() {
        pDlg = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
        pDlg.setMessage(processMessage);
        pDlg.setIndeterminate(true);
        pDlg.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        pDlg.setCancelable(false);
        pDlg.show();
    }

    public void addParameter(String name, String value) {
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(name, value));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        if(!this.hideProcessMessage)
            showProgressDialog();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        String url = urls[0];
        String result = "";

        HttpResponse response = doResponse(url);

        if (response == null) {
            onPostExecute(result);
            return result;
        } else {
            try {
                result = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent());
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
        try{
           callback.onTaskComplete(new JSONObject(response));
        }catch (JSONException e){
            Log.v(TAG, "Problemas para obter resposta do servidor.");
        }
    }

    public void handleResponse(String response, Context context) {
        try {
            JSONObject jso = new JSONObject(response);
            returnWS = jso;
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // Estabelece conexão e define timeout do socket
    private HttpParams getHttpParams() {
        HttpParams htpp = new BasicHttpParams();

        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(htpp, CONN_TIMEOUT);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(htpp, SOCKET_TIMEOUT);

        return htpp;
    }

    private HttpResponse doResponse(String url) {
        // Use our connection and data timeouts as parameters for our
        // DefaultHttpClient
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(getHttpParams());
        HttpResponse response = null;

        try {
            switch (taskType) {
                case PUT_TASK:
                    HttpPut httpPut = new HttpPut(url);
                    httpPut.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, "UTF-8"));
                    response = httpclient.execute(httpPut);
                    break;

                case POST_TASK:
                    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, "UTF-8"));
                    response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
                    break;

                case GET_TASK:
                    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
                    response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
                    break;

                case DELETE_TASK:
                    HttpDelete httpDelete = new HttpDelete(url);
                    response = httpclient.execute(httpDelete);
                    break;


            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
            if (!hideProcessMessage)
                pDlg.dismiss();
        }

        return response;
    }

    private String inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {

        String line = "";
        StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();

        // Wrap a BufferedReader around the InputStream
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

        try {
            // Read response until the end
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                total.append(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
        }

        // Return full string
        return total.toString();
    }

}
```

Sua classe principal, que fizer a requisição, terá que implementar a `interface`:

```
public class ActivityIncluirItemPedido implements AsyncTaskCompleteListener {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       [...]
    }


    protected void clickBuscarDados(View view){

      WebServiceTask webServiceTask = new WebServiceTask(WebServiceTask.POST_TASK, view.getContext(), "Buscando dados do usuário", this);

      //Se houver algum parametro para filtro no back-end
      webServiceTask.addParameter("idUsuario", _idUsuario.getText().toString());

      //Endereço do WS back-end que receberá a chamada
      webServiceTask.execute(new String[]{"localhost:8080/WSLocal/UsuarioWS"});
  }


    [....]
    @Override
    public void onTaskComplete(JSONObject result) throws JSONException {
       JSONArray jsonArray = result.getJSONArray("<Chave do Json">);


    }


}
```

Desta forma, quando o método chamar `onPostExecute`, ele fará referência a sua classe que implementa a interface `AsyncTaskCompleteListener`.

Você pode fazer da seguinte maneira também:
1 - Receba a mensagem do teu back-end e salve-a em uma array de strings

```
 Array of choices
String colors[] = {"Red","Blue","White","Yellow","Black", "Green","Purple","Orange","Grey"};

// Selection of the spinner
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.myspinner);

// Application of the Array to the Spinner
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,   android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, colors);
spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); // The drop down view
spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
```

Comment: @CamilaYamamoto Pelo que entendi, você ira chamar o teu webservice, pegar valores e quer colocar eles em um Spinner, correto? Se for isso mesmo, você precisa interpretar a resposta do teu ws, adicionar em uma array de strings e adicionar "manualmente".

Comment: @CamilaYamamoto Fiz um ajuste na reposta e adicionei por final um exemplo de como fazer o que comentei ali logo acima, se tiver dúvidas, me chama. Não desanime!

Comment: Pra mim, o java teve sua acensão quando todos conseguiram ver na prática a multiplataforma, etc...quando vieram as novas linguagens, cross-plataform, todos começaram a se questionar a respeito...acho que o Java tem seus benefícios, assim como todas as outras linguagens também tem...Agora todos estão apaixonados pelo ionic, angular, e assim vai, a cada ciclo, uma nova linguagem do momento..

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52830/discussion-between-carlos-bridi-and-camila-yamamoto).

Comment: Obrigada Carlos! você me ajudou a estudar mais! Muito obrigada pela boa vontade!  Nos, os novatos, precisamos de mais gente como vocês...  eh duro aprender! e vocês **nao estão** nos cobrando ainda mais.... muti pelo contrario, ajudam e vão dando mais toques!!!  _eh assim que a gente aprende e tem mais respeito por vocês!_  ta ouvindo ai @Ack Lay ??  feliz aqui!

Comment: Olá Camila, desculpe, ontem a operadora de internet fez manutenção na rede e não consegui mais te responder no chat. Se você subir esse projeto algum dia no Git, posso te ajudar a fazer um refactoring e separar os conceitos das classes melhor...Obrigado e continue em frente ;)

Comment: bacana!  obrigada!

Answer (score 0):

Além da resposta do Carlos Bridi, há também um jeito igualmente legal, que é semelhante ao funcionamento do firebase...
Ou seja, você cria uma interface e recebe ela no construtor da asynctask e, por fim, na hora da chamar a asynctask, você cria um novo objeto e programa o que quer que a asynctask faça.
Exemplo:

```
public interface IResultado {

    Object processamento(); // o tipo pode ser outro também, variamento conforme a necessidade
    void resultado(Object resultado);

}
```

A asynctask genérica

```
public class AsyncTaskResultado extends AsyncTask<Object, Integer, Object> {

    private IResultado results;

    public AsyncTaskResultado(IResultado results) {
        this.results = results;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... objects) {
        return results.processamento();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object resultado) {
        results.resultado(resultado);
    }
}
```

Na activity...

```
void minhaRequisição(){

    new AsyncTaskResultado(new IResultado() {

                @Override
                public Object processamento() {
                    // aqui voce programa o que quer que a asynctask faça...
                    // e deverá retornar um objeto
                    return "myJson"; // aqui retorna seu JSON.
                    }

                @Override
                public void resultado(Object resultado) { // o JSON vai vir pra cá
                   // aqui o que ela vai fazer após terminar... 
                   // no seu caso, preenche o spinner com o json (não esqueça de dar um cast)
                }

            }).execute();
    }
```

Isso é só um exemplo. Use a sua criatividade para moldá-la a sua necessidade.
Essa asynctask dá pra ser usada várias vezes. O que vai mudar é o que você programa na hora que dá um new nela...